# SSE Blocked in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, server-sent-events

I'm setting up an SSE connection, using a Java server and a JavaScript client.
On Firefox browser everything works fine.
On google chrome it also works, as long as I use a local server like this:

```
var source = new EventSource('http://localhost:1234/SSE');
```

The problem starts when I try using a remote server, like this:

```
var source = new EventSource('http://15.17.252.14:1234/SSE');
```

In this case, as long as the server is opened, no notifications are received on the client side, even though they are sent from the server.

When the server is stopped, all notifications are received at once.

The problem persists even if the server is local, and the IP passed to `EventSource()` is my own local  IP.

Comment: `[sse]` is the tag for x86 SIMD.  If it looks like there are 2 tags for exactly the same thing, mouseover them: one of them is probably something completely different with the same name or initials.

Comment: I've posted an answer, which basically amounts to some troubleshooting ideas. If they do not help, I recommend you expand your answer to show both the server-side script and the client-side script, and describe which web server and version. Search stackoverflow for Minimal Reproducible Example.

Answer (score 0):

Is the HTML page (the one making the `EventSource` call) being served from exactly the same URL? I.e. from `http://15.17.252.14:1234/` ?

If not, you are possibly hitting a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) problem. CORS works exactly the same way for SSE as it does for AJAX, so there is plenty of advice out there.

That doesn't explain why you get the data when you stop the server, though. That is normally due to your server-side script caching the output, or the web server caching the output. E.g. if you are using PHP `@ob_flush();flush();` is the idiom to push the data to clients immediately.

Neither of those theories explain why it works for Firefox though. Is there an https server on that same URL, and could Chrome be set up to try and force https? Could the http and https servers be configured slightly differently, so one is caching?  (Another explanation would be that Chrome is set up to use a proxy server, and Firefox is not.)

A good troubleshooting tip is to use `curl` to test your server:

```
curl http://15.17.252.14:1234/SSE
```

And, of course, the network tabs of the browsers, and compare the three to try and work out what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using the same URL for both scenarios (localhost or 15.17.252.14). My chrome is not using Proxy. Anyway, I got it working now, but I don't really know how. I changed something in the allowed apps on the Windows Defender Firewall, and it makes the SSE work for chrome. However, when I tried going back to the previous configuration, it still works... Can anyone please explain what these settings mean? What is the difference between an application allowed for Domain/Private/Public/All three, and how does it affect SSE?